# Detect whether user is logged in to site A from site B, using Firebase Auth

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, user-experience, cross-site

Our new site, `example.pro`, uses Firebase authentication. A small subset of our old `example.com` users will pay to subscribe to the new site but most will continue to use the old site anonymously.

Firebase Auth makes it easy to remain logged in to `example.pro`, but these privileged users might visit the old site for various reasons, including by mistake, and from different devices. So for these users I would like to detect whether they are logged in and <s>redirect them as transparently as possible</s> offer them a link to the new site that they can ignore and continue to use the old site, if they wish.

I have considered placing an iframe from `example.pro` on `example.com` that would trigger a dialog. Would that be safe?

Do you have a better idea?

[I've edited my question to clarify that the old site does not use any authentication or means of identifying the user, and to clarify that I want users to be able to choose to remain on the old site]

Comment: Hello, are your questions resolved? You can accept the answer if yes so others know that this is resolved else feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: @Dharmaraj, I haven't decided. I'm not afraid of a purely technological, rather complicated solution like yours, but there is also a UX component to it. Both domains are based on a single Firebase project. Every future (or potential) subscriber needs to first create an account - should that be on example.com or app.example.com? Because they might return to example.com... if their account is first created on example.com and immediately after subscribing, a custom claim is set and they can be redirected to the app, where they will need to log in. (cont'd below)

Comment: Meanwhile, they are still logged in to example.com which is pretty meaningless as there is no functionality available to them on that site, but it could give us a way to help them get to the app, where they need to go. They can log out of example.com  if they wish, but for as long as they remain logged in to example.com, either 1) a notice could advise them to click through to app.example.com, or 2) they could be redirected automatically. Is there any harm in leaving them logged in indefinitely?

Comment: it shouldn't be an issue leaving them logged in on tje site where Firebase authentication is working. They'll keep rolling the tokens. When it comes to your other subdomains you must make sure you handle your tokens carefully. Also you can setup your servers in such a way when user logs in you create a session in database and validate each time if that session still exists. When users logout, delete that from db. So next time when user has logged out from a the main domain or any, even if they have a valid token for other subdomain but you'll reject requests as the ssn in removed from db.

Comment: So that kind of acts as a domain wide logout. I also make sure the token user is using is created in the latest session. So far no issues.

Comment: Okay, I'll keep all that in mind, thanks. So far, using firebaseui with email link, and testing with several thousand users, I haven't had to deal with tokens or cookies at all. Create account, login, logout "just works"...

Comment: Though when it comes to authentication over subdomains then you would have to implement your own custom solution.

Comment: The subdomain will be the only valid destination for app users. Once logged out of the conventional, feature-less example.com, they'll not return there except by accident. That's why I'd like to keep them logged in. As I said, logging in to that site, all one can do is manage subscriptions (using the Stripe extension).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231732/discussion-between-dharmaraj-and-ken).

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Authentication does not support multi domain authentication or something like SSO. The best you can do you implement [JWT](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken) based custom auth that primarily relies on Firebase Auth. I've done that in a couple of ways and the auth flow mentioned below works best for me:

1. Select a domain for Firebase auth (this will be the domain where users will be logged in via Firebase directly)
2. When user visits one of your subdomain, let's say app.domain.com for this example, you check if there is any token present in the localStorage of browser (or any local storage of the respective platform). If yes, that means they are logged in. (I'll come back to the token later)
3. If the user ain't logged in on the subdomain, go to the domain where Firebase Auth works, make a call your server with the Firebase IdToken, verify that and generate a temporary token and return it. Make sure you store it in your database on server side. After that, redirect user back to the subdomain where they were trying to log in with the new token in query param. For example, your URL may look  like: `https://app.domain.com/login?temp_token=thatTempTokenGeneratedOnServerSide1234`.
4. Make another request containing that temp token to your server from the subdomain and validate it (like check the UID and if it is expired and maybe if the IP of user is same when the token was created).
5. Generate another JWT (preferably one with long life) (You might want to look at [Rolling Token Auth](https://www.okta.com/identity-101/what-is-token-based-authentication/) for better security) and return it to the client and store it on client. This JWT ideally would contain only the UID of that user. So whenever the user makes any subsequent requests to the server from that subdomain, add that token in request header (or keep it in cookies as per your convenience) then verify it on server side for processing the data.
6. If the token is expired, repeat the auth flow.

I've been using this for a while and found no issues. Just make sure you read about the access tokens and refresh tokens about how that works. I'll try to add a flowchart asap meanwhile feel free to ask any questions.