# Share firebase authentication across sites hosted on the same firebase project

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, cross-domain

I have two domains hosted on the same Firebase project. `domain.com` and `app.domain.com`

I have my authentication logic on the main page `domain.com`. I need that when a user logs in from
`domain.com` they are automatically logged into `app.domain.com` when they redirect to it.

Comment: That's not possible in Firebase Auth directly. You would have to implement some custom solution as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67286020/13130697)

Comment: Thanks, @Dharmaraj. Points me in the right direction